# Problem wih softmax function in the output layer

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, softmax

I have a tensor stored in `a` as below:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1 ],
       [0.2 ],
       [0.4 ],
       [0.15],
       [0.15]], dtype=float32)>
```

when I apply a softmax function on it,

```
a_tf = tf.nn.softmax(a)
```

I am getting a tensor as shown below

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

although I would expect normalized values between 0 and 1 that add up to 1.

Indeed, when I use the softmax definition code

```
a_tf = out_put = (tf.exp(a)) / (tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(a)))
```

I get the tensor as expected:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1799347 ],
       [0.19885859],
       [0.24288644],
       [0.18916014],
       [0.18916014]], dtype=float32)>
```

Can someone please explain why the first code snippet is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input array (or tensor) has shape `(5, 1)`, and by default, `tf.nn.softmax` operates on the last dimension. You might see what goes wrong now, because the last dimension is an individual element, which is then normalized with softmax to 1.0

You have then two options:

- Specify `axis=0` to `tf.nn.softmax` so the operation is performed on the first and not the last dimension.
- Reshape the array to shape `(1, 5)` which would work with a default call to `tf.nn.softmax`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It cleared up my doubt regarding how the softmax function works.